# Git forensics: all changes on dev branch disappeared after merge into master

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

My team just discovered that all changes (edits, added files) from a development branch disappeared when that branch was merged into "master".

```
-- A --- B --- D --   "master"
    \         /
      -- C --       "dev"
```

`git diff D B` shows no differences.

`git diff D C` shows lots of differences.

There should have been no merge conflicts.

The merge was probably performed using SourceTree.

Is there a simple explanation for how such a thing might have happened?  We'd like to avoid doing it again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get that in Git is by explicitly asking for it.  There are various ways to do it, there's various workflows for which that's a legitimate merge result, but it's not the default and you can't just fatfinger the request, you have to ask for it. One way is a `-s ours` merge. Another is to do a `git reset HEAD` before committing the merge.   If SourceTree makes it easy to fatfinger that, that's on them.

Comment: This is a helpful response.  We still don't know conclusively what happened, but users thrashing in SourceTree sounds totally plausible. Thanks!